# Javascript OOP: binding method to event handler

Tags: javascript, oop, this

I'm new to JS and I understand functions are the way to declare "class like" structures.
I'm trying to do something like this:

```
function Game() {
  // Class stuff

  this.handleClick = function(e) {
    alert(e);
  }

  // Bind event to method previously defined
  $('#board').bind('click', function(e) {
    this.handleClick(e);              // <--- THIS IS THE PROBLEMATIC LINE
  });
}
```

Now, if in the "problematic line" I write:

```
  handleClick(e)
```

I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: handleClick is not defined`.

Instead, if I write:

```
  this.handleClick(e);
```

I get `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLCanvasElement> has no method 'handleClick'`

But then, if I do:

```
function Game() {
  // Class stuff

  this.handleClick = function(e) {
    alert(e);
  }

  var game = this;                    // <--- I ASSIGN this TO board
  // Bind event to method previously defined
  $('#board').bind('click', function(e) {
    game.handleClick(e);              // <--- THIS WORKS!! WHY????
  });
}
```

It works!?!?!

My questions are:

1. Why does this happen this way? I know `this` can be problematic, but why assigning it to a variable changes it like that?
2. Am I doing this wrong? Is there a better way to achieve something like this in a more elegant way?

Comment: `this` depends on **how** you call a function. In your case `this` is the DOM element.

Comment: Ok, but why when I assign this to a variable it changes its value?

Comment: Because it loses its special meaning and simply stores whatever `this` was at the time of assignment.

Comment: `this` outside the event handler is a different `this`. By caching it you're maintaining the outer value. When you introduce a new scope, your `this` will change according to _how_ the function is called. In your case, it's called like `fn.call(element, event, ...args)` where `element` is `this`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You found the one hole in Javascript's implementation of closures. (If you don't know what closures are, don't worry about it.)

`this` in Javascript references the object on which the function was called. So if you have an object with a property that happens to be assigned the value of a function, and you call that property, the `this` pointer references the object. It does not reference whatever `this` was where the function was created, nor does it reference the function itself.

```
var object = {};
object.myfunc = function() { console.log(this); } //<-- this will refer to object
object.myfunc();
```

In the case of an event handler, the handler function (in pure Javascript, ignoring jQuery) gets assigned to the DOM element, so it gets called from that element and hence `this` points to the DOM element.

Using a local variable, like `game` in your example above, means that the function you created (a "closure") will "close" around that variable, capturing the values of any variable in scope at the place the function was defined. Any variable *except* `this`. So your work-around is a very common way to handle this.

Another common way to handle this would be to use a library like Underscore.js which has a function called `bind` that does some higher-order-function magic to make sure `this` always points to what you want.

```
$('board').bind('click', _.bind(function(e) {
  this.handleClick(e);
}, this));
```

For this reason, Underscore.js is one of my favorite Javascript libraries (after jQuery), and I use it almost exclusively for the bind function.

Comment: You can also use the native `Function.prototype.bind` in all current browsers.

Comment: There is no "hole", because `this` is not a variable!